# How can I set the database name using Serilog.Sink.MongoDB in appsettings.json in ASP.NET (Blazor)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, serilog, appsettings

I have Serilog set up to write to MongoDB via `Serilog.Sinks.MongoDB`.

I'm using `appsettings.json` for my configuration (*with my password masked by XXXXXXX*):

```json
{
  "Name": "MongoDB",
  "Args": {
  "databaseUrl": "mongodb+srv://AtlasUser:XXXXXXX/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true",
  "databaseName": "MyLogs",
  "collectionName": "MyLoggerCollection",
  "cappedMaxSizeMb": "1024",
  "cappedMaxDocuments": "50000"
}
```

This results in a database with the name `test` and a collection called 'MyLoggerCollection'.

`"databaseName": "MyLogs"` seems to be taking no effect.

The database created is still named `test` (I guess the default?).

How can I set the database name to `MyLogs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying the database name as `test` in your connection string, which [is where the database name used comes from](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mongodb#json-microsoftextensionsconfiguration) - not the `databaseName` property.

> "databaseUrl": "mongodb://username:password@ip:port**/**dbName**?authSource=admin"`

This should work:

```
{
  "Name": "MongoDB",
  "Args": {
  "databaseUrl": "mongodb+srv://AtlasUser:XXXXXXX/MyLogs?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true",
  "collectionName": "MyLoggerCollection",
  "cappedMaxSizeMb": "1024",
  "cappedMaxDocuments": "50000"
}
```